# Stop Warning: date() [function.date]: from localhost

Tags: php, date, timezone, warnings

> Warning: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected ............

There are many web applications that spring up this particular error.  I could set

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

But that is not the solution I am looking for.

Can I do something from system level.  It happens only on `LOCALHOST` not on the actual production server.

**Default set in php.ini is date.timezone = America/Los_Angeles**

**[update]** edited php.ini

> Warning: phpinfo() [function.phpinfo]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are required to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier

Comment: Well, if you're not looking for one then... do the other?

Comment: You edited the right `php.ini`? Usually PHP uses different inis for webserver, cli and cgi. try `phpinfo()`

Comment: It isn't clear what your exact question is: if php.ini is not system level enough, or if PHP still triggers the warning after you changed it.

Comment: @KingCrunch Nope have not edit the php.ini

Comment: @Jean There are three answers, all telling you the same thing. Find the php.ini loaded by your server - phpinfo(1) will tell you the location. Then set a value for date.timezone. Is there any particular reason why you didn't accept any of these answers?

Answer (score 8):

The reason it is happending on one server and not the other is the `php.ini` setting [`date.timezone=`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone).

You would still need to pick an actual value though. You assuredly don't have one. Or in the wrong php.ini version (there's one for CLI and one for mod_php).

Comment: **Default set in php.ini is date.timezone = America/Los_Angeles**

Comment: phpinfo() ERROR ---

Warning: phpinfo() [function.phpinfo]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier.

Answer (score 1):

As the other posters have mentioned, setting date.timezone in the php.ini file is the way to go. If you are still seeing the error about needing to set it, did you restart your web server (apache, IIS, etc) after setting the php.ini?

Also, the warning from phpinfo means the rest of the output should still be showing. Make sure you're editing the correct php.ini file according to the phpinfo() output.

That will likely get you working as you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

to remove this warning from your project

There are 2 ways to do so...

1)
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
include this file in your index.php file
This will work only for your current project

2)
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); 
or inlude this file in your php.ini file
This will work for every project

thnx :)

Answer (score 0):

As the warning says...

> use the [date.timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) setting

Just configure this with [your timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) in php.ini, and all will be well for all apps on your server.

**EDIT** If you are still having this problem after having configured this, you will probably find that your system uses more than one php.ini file. To find out which ini file is used for your web server, use [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).

Comment: phpinfo() ERROR --- Warning: phpinfo() [function.phpinfo]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are required to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier

Comment: Look at the path of php.ini as displayed by the output of `phpinfo()` - ignore the error for now - and make sure you have defined the default timezone in *that* php.ini file.

Answer (score -1):

It works by setting

```
date.timezone = Asia/Calcutta
```

For details go to: [PHP Documentation - Asia Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php)