# Laravel include a library that uses autoload.php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) library inside my home controller, but I don't know how to include it. The library's documentation uses this:

```
require_once '/path/to/Faker/src/autoload.php';
$faker = Faker\Factory::create();
```

But Laravel has a different way of [loading classes](http://laravel.com/docs/loading), but I didn't find an example with such a library.

So how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you added it using composer?
I use a lib that I have installer with composer ([Imagine](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine)) and I wanted to use composer loading script so I did this in start.php:

```
// Composer package
require_once  $GLOBALS['laravel_paths']['base'] . 'vendor' . DS . 'autoload.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Registering a namespace](http://laravel.com/docs/loading#namespaces), it should take care of what you need. Faker follows the PSR0 standard for namespaces, so you need need to tell laravel how to find those files. In your `application/start.php` file place these directives:

```
Autoloader::namespaces(array(
    'Faker' => path('libraries').'path/to/Faker/src/Faker',
));
```

Hope that helps!

Edit:

Furthermore I realized that if you move the src/Faker folder into `application/libraries` as `application/libraries/Faker` it should be loaded automatically.

Comment: A couple of problems. Your "move to libraries" suggestion doesn't work (I get _Class 'Faker\Factory' not found_). Your first also doesn't work (at least I think so), it's giving me the _you are required to use date.timezone..._

Comment: Regarding the date.timezone error check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704522/stop-warning-date-function-date-from-localhost

Regarding the other issue, If I get a moment today I will try to install Faker myself.

Comment: Well I got this working using the library method. See https://github.com/Kindari/faker/commit/e7e84a65480dc4ba0b9b5ae1e04a37f474d3dd22#diff-74 - This is a fresh clone of laravel with the latest faker moved into libraries. No other configuration was needed. `application/routes.php` shows the usage.